# rewrite rule with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i make this in htaccess for rewrite url

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?username=$1 [QSA]    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

But Now i work hard to change it to be like this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2}).([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?prefix=$1&username=$2 [QSA]
```

and its work fine .. 
but after change {2} to be {2,4} in rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2,4}).([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?prefix=$1&username=$2 [QSA]
```

it make website very slow ..

final link should be sitename.com/prefix.name == index.php?prefix=$1&username=$2

can any one help me to rewrite the rule ?!

**Update :**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 400 /connect2/error.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 401 /connect2/error.php?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 /connect2/error.php?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 /connect2/error.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 500 /connect2/error.php?error=500
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /connect2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/objects.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

########## Begin - File injection protection, by SigSiu.net
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
########## End - File injection protection

########## Begin - Basic antispam Filter, by SigSiu.net
## I removed some common words, tweak to your liking
## This code uses PCRE and works only with Apache 2.x.
## This code will NOT work with Apache 1.x servers.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(ambien|blue\spill|cialis|cocaine|ejaculation|erectile)\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(erections|hoodia|huronriveracres|impotence|levitra|libido)\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(lipitor|phentermin|pro[sz]ac|sandyauer|tramadol|troyhamby)\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \b(ultram|unicauca|valium|viagra|vicodin|xanax|ypxaieo)\b [NC]
## Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.
RewriteRule .* - [F]
## Note: The previous lines are a "compressed" version
## of the filters. You can add your own filters as:
## RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bbadword\b [NC,OR]
## where "badword" is the word you want to exclude.
########## End - Basic antispam Filter, by SigSiu.net

########## Begin - Advanced server protection - query strings, referrer and config
# Advanced server protection, version 3.2 - May 2011
# by Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos

## Disallow PHP Easter Eggs (can be used in fingerprinting attacks to determine
## your PHP version). See http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php and
## http://osvdb.org/12184 for more information
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

## SQLi first line of defense, thanks to Radek Suski (SigSiu.net) @
## http://www.sigsiu.net/presentations/fortifying_your_joomla_website.html
## May cause problems on legitimate requests
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

#Block mySQL injects
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|’|”|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark) [NC,OR]

## Referrer filtering for common media files. Replace with your own domain name.
## This blocks most common fingerprinting attacks ;)
## Note: Change www\.example\.com with your own domain name, substituting the
## dots with \.  i.e. use www\.example\.com for www.example.com
# RewriteRule ^images/stories/([^/]+/)*([^/.]+\.)+(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# RewriteRule \.(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico)$ - [F]

## Disallow visual fingerprinting of Joomla! sites (module position dump)
## Initial idea by Brian Teeman and Ken Crowder, see:
## http://www.slideshare.net/brianteeman/hidden-joomla-secrets
## Improved by @nikosdion to work more efficiently and handle template
## and tmpl query parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl=(component|system) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)t(p|emplate|mpl)= [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

## Disallow access to htaccess.txt, configuration.php, configuration.php-dist and php.ini
RewriteRule ^(htaccess\.txt|configuration\.php(-dist)?|php\.ini)$ - [F]

########## End - Advanced server protection - query strings, referrer and config

########## Begin - Optimal default expiration time
## Note: this might cause problems and you might have to comment it out by
## placing a hash in front of this section's lines
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expiration control
ExpiresActive On

# Default expiration: 1 hour after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 hour"

# CSS and JS expiration: 1 week after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 week"

# Image files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/smil "now plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
########## End - Optimal expiration time

ServerSignature Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,4})\.([\w-]+)$ index.php?prefix=$1&username=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,4})\.([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?prefix=$1&username=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

This single rule takes care of all cases. `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Only `[a-z]` has been specified because the rule is now case-insensitive by using `[NC]`. Trailing slash is also optional `/?`.

Comment: but it still the same issue when i put your code .. 

in firebug it make errors load more and more and more 

that mean when i have one error in firebug !! 

GET http://localhost/connect2/img/slide-5.jpg 404 (Not Found) 

it load more an more to becomes 2 then 3 then 4 then 5 ~ 99999999 

GET http://localhost/connect2/img/slide-5.jpg 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost/connect2/img/slide-5.jpg 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost/connect2/img/slide-5.jpg 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost/connect2/img/slide-5.jpg 404 (Not Found) 

what the problem ?!

Comment: In which folder have you placed your .htaccess file?

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /connect2` just below `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: its already exist .. 

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    ErrorDocument 400 /connect2/error.php?error=400
    ErrorDocument 401 /connect2/error.php?error=401
    ErrorDocument 403 /connect2/error.php?error=403
    ErrorDocument 404 /connect2/error.php?error=404
    ErrorDocument 500 /connect2/error.php?error=500
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /connect2/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/objects.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,4})\.([\w-]+)$ index.php?prefix=$1&username=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

Comment: Please update it as part of the question. It becomes more readable then.

Comment: You have not yet added the `RewriteCond` to the rule. They need to be repeated with this rule as well.

Comment: sorry how to added RewriteCond  to rule ?!

Comment: Just like in my answer!